# In which situations we can use public static void main(String... args) instead of public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: java, string, program-entry-point

In which situations can we use 
`public static void main(String... args)`
 instead of 
`public static void main(String[] args)`?

Comment: For standalone java class with main method, there is no difference. You can run with both signature, I am using java-8

Answer (score 3):

In **all** situations where we have [Java 1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) or greater. Prior to Java 1.5, there were no varargs so you could not use `String...`

Answer (score 0):

`...` is just syntactic sugaring over an array declaration. You can always use `public static void main(String... args)`, assuming you're using at least Java 5.0 (which introduced the `...` operator).

Answer (score 0):

For Java 1.5 and above, you can use any of this two. In case of ... argument array is not necessarily of String type.